# Use tokens for cck field default value

Tags: 7, nodes, entities, tokens

Is there any module or code hack to use tokens to set cck field default values ?
i have a content type with contact details fieldset, this fieldset have some fields to collect data from current logged in user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed: [Field default token](https://drupal.org/project/field_default_token).

> This module enables to use tokens as field default values.

See the [related core discussion](https://drupal.org/node/1070878) if you're interested.